# How am I able to use ternary operator to add classes where argument is greater than/less than statement using React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a filter on an image and i would like the image to change class when the currentClickPower is greater or equal to 5. As of right now the filter works if i put it on the original image class but it will not change once the arguement is met. I am using React, do i need to use some sort of useEffect to make it re render?   [css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg8T4.png)  [more css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSGqH.png)    [states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSlRg.png)   [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8FtO.png)

````
``` <img className={currentClickPower >= 5 ? "Orb BlueOrb": "Orb"} src={Orb} alt="Mana Orb" height="200"></img> ```
````

Here is state code

````
``` const [currentClickPower, setClickPower] = useState(1) ```
````

and function that updates click power (always adds 1)

````
```  const UpgradeClickPower = (newPower, upgradeCost) => {
    if (currentMana < currentClickUpgradeCost) {
      alert('Not Enough Mana!!')
    } else {
      setMana(currentMana - currentClickUpgradeCost)
      setClickPower(newPower)
      setClickUpgradeCost(upgradeCost)
    }
  } 
```
````

Comment: is `currentClickPower` a `state` or a `prop` value?

Comment: currentClickPower is a state value

Comment: then it should work. can you create a minimal example and share it https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This isn't enough code. A [simplified version](https://codepen.io/brendanbond/pen/MWVVEyK) of your code runs fine, which tells me that your problem lies with your CSS or some other portion of your React code. Post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: alright ive uploaded some photos please let me know if that helps or not